# How encrypt files before uploading?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, encryption, ng-file-upload

ng-file-upload is a very effective library and I would like to use it but after adding a encryption system.

I want to encrypt files with RSA protocol in javascript before uploading them. Do you have any idea how to do this with ng-file-upload ?

Is there a way to change blob before uploading the files ?

PS : encryption must be in javascript because I can't use HTTPS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are your intentions to modify **ng-file-upload** ? If not, you could use the `$ngfBlobUrl` that they provide for each file.

Read that using HTML5 fileReader API to get the binary data. Encrypt this data and convert it back to a blob (functions to do so are well found on the interwebz). You can then send this back to the server.

Comment: Thx for the answer.
I would prefer not to fork ng-file-upload if it is possible. But in fact my issue is more about cutting the file is small pieces, encrypt each piece and then send all of them. Because on big files, I can't encrypt it in one time.

Comment: Alright, here's what you have to do.

Get the blobData from the blobURL

Split the string in chunks (I go to about 10000 characters each)

Encrypt the chunks individually, then when all is done, convert that array to JSON string, then save that string to a text file (with blob). 

Reverse this process to decrypt the file.

I strongly recommend using **WebWorkers**, as they work on separate threads and do not lag the user interface, as this process can get heavy.

Check the source code of pm.highshare.com, i've codded this last year, hope it helps.

Comment: Ok I better understand how to do this. It seems a good approach. I try it !

Comment: Use `Upload.base64DataUrl(file).then(...)` instead of $ngfBlobUrl which is for internal use only.

Comment: Yep I saw that. Thx.